# Adding a NSDictionary to a NSArray duplicates the first NSDictionary every time

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

So I pulled some `JSON` data from a web service which is stored in an `NSArray` called `_infoFromJSON`. Each array element in `_infoFromJSON` essentially has a dictionary of key/value pairs. The goal is to add them to `myVehicleObject` which is an `NSMutableArray`

```
for (NSDictionary* myDictionary in _infoFromJSON) {
    myVehicleObject *vehicleInMembersProfile;
    vehicleInMembersProfile = [[myVehicleObject alloc] init];
    vehicleInMembersProfile.make = [[_infoFromJSON objectAtIndex:carCount] objectForKey:@"make"];
    vehicleInMembersProfile.carName = [[_infoFromJSON objectAtIndex:carCount] objectForKey:@"nickname"];
    vehicleInMembersProfile.year = [[_infoFromJSON objectAtIndex:carCount] objectForKey:@"year"];
    carCount ++;
    [self.myVehicleObject addObject:vehicleInMembersProfile] ;
};
```

With the above code I sort of achieved it, however it keeps adding the same 1st dictionary to `myVehicleObject`, so it inserts the same `NSDictionary` 4 times  In the past I have used this:

```
[self.myVehicleObject addObject:[vehicleInMembersProfile copy]] ;
```

When I do it it throws the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[myVehicleObject copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xab4e130'
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks!

**Update** Requested Sample JSON:

```
{
        color = SILVER;
        engine = "";
        id = "CF270B81-3821-4585-8C90-7089D7A8654E";
        imageUrl = "https://www.someprotectedurl.com/somefile.png";
        licensePlate = "ABC-123";
        make = Honda;
        model = "CR-V";
        nickname = "My CR-V";
        vin = "XX551234687687687654";
        year = 2009;
    }
```

Comment: it would be helpful to see the JSON?, and also how did you initialize carcount

Comment: This is not how you use `forin` loops...

Comment: Since you're fast enumerating, why don't you just do `vehicleInMembersProfile.make = myDictionary[@"make"];` etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may or may not be related to the problem, but your `forin` loop is completely broken.  Whether or not your incorrect usage is the actual cause of the problem, this is something you should definitely fix as it can do nothing but cause problems.

If you want to use `indexOfObject:` to grab an object at an index of the array you're iterating through, you should use a regular `for` loop:

```
for (int carCount=0; index < [_infoFromJSON count]; ++carCount) {
    // loop body remains identical to what you have... 
    // except remove carCount++;
}
```

But for what you're doing, a `forin` loop is indeed better, and `forin` loops can be faster since they can be handled in batches.  But if you're using a `forin` loop, use the object you're defining in the loop declaration:

```
for(NSDictionary* myDictionary in _infoFromJSON) {
    // myDictionary is a reference to an object in _infoFromJSON, 
    //for whatever given index it is currently working on

    myVehicleObject *vehicleInMembersProfile = [[myVehicleObject alloc] init];
    vehicleInMembersProfile.make = myDictionary[@"make"];
    vehicleInMembersProfile.carName = myDictionary[@"nickname"];
    vehicleInMembersProfile.year = myDictionary[@"year"];
    [self.myVehicleObject addObject:vehicleInMembersProfile];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Good point and I am using it correctly now. Turns out the actual problem may have been because I hadnt completely pulled all fields it was appearing to be duplicated every time. Either way great answer on using for/in correctly so I am accepting it. It may help a newb or a dev like me that learned Objective C in bits an pieces.

Answer (score 2):

The error is that your class does not implement NSCopying.

However, there isn't any need to copy the object here. You're creating a new object each time through the loop. If you insert a copy, you're just pointlessly throwing away the original each time. The more likely cause if you're seeing odd loop behavior is that your loop is mixing up different kinds of enumeration, as [pointed out by nhgrif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23943783/50742). Instead of accessing `[_infoFromJSON objectAtIndex:carCount]`, just use `myDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a for loop rather than a foreach since you need the array index, I would code it like this

```
NSMutableArray *vehiclesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i < [_infoFromJSON count]; i++)
{
    //create vehicle
    myVehicleObject *vehicleInMembersProfile = [[myVehicleObject alloc] init];
    vehicleInMembersProfile.make = _infoFromJSON[i][@"make"];
    vehicleInMembersProfile.carName = _infoFromJSON[i][@"nickname"];
    vehicleInMembersProfile.year = _infoFromJSON[i][@"year"];

    //finally add the vehicle to the array
    [vehiclesArray addObject:vehicleInMembersProfile] ;
}
```

I wasn't sure what `myVehicleObject` was , and why is it the same type you are adding to itself, so I changed it to an array. But you get the point.

Comment: A `forin` loop is definitely better here... but if you're going to use a regular `for` loop, be careful with your iterator.  I fixed it for you, but you were skipping the first index and ending out with an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: The index actually isn't used except to get the current item, which is what fast enumeration already does.

Comment: @nhgrif thanks a lot, you guys maybe right as I am just an ios amateur!!